# Concatenate files on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are getting several files in one s3 folder ( 130K files , combined size is 2GB ). Each file has Json data , could be one or many records.  I need to merge these files into a single Json file and store it on s3. I don't want to download the files to local machine and then combine.  Is there a way to do it using AWS SDK for Java ?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to use **Amazon Athena** to read and combine the files. Athena is a managed query service based on [Presto](http://prestodb.github.io/) that can read many different file formats.

The steps flow would be:

- Create a table definition in Athena that defines the input file formats and the location of the input data

  - (You can use an AWS Glue crawler to do this for you)
- Use [CREATE TABLE AS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html) to query the source table

  - This will retrieve data from the source files and write the output to a new location
  - You can specify the output format and location

Think of Athena as a "query layer" on top of Amazon S3. It reads the input from all files in a given S3 directory and can then output the results back to S3. You can do a simple `SELECT *` to copy all the data, or you can choose to manipulate the results by selecting only desired fields and entries (using `SELECT` and `WHERE`).

Athena can be run from the management console, or triggered via a normal AWS SDK (such as Java).

The benefit of using Athena is that there is no need to download the source files and upload the result — this will all be done by Athena.

Athena is charged based on the **amount of data read from disk**. Compressed files reduce this cost.

Comment: John , thanks for the reply. We need the combined file in Json format and I believe Athena allows csv . Is there a way to get the merged file in Json format ?

Comment: Yes, it can read and write JSON. See: [JSON SerDe Libraries - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html)