# merge json files in AWS S3 into a single file

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have thousands of json files stored in AWS S3. The keys are repeated across files and I am not interested in the values. Just the keys. I am trying to find an efficient way to merge all these files into a single json file. I tried using AWS Glue for this, but the crawler didn't collect anything. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58513223/1032785

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by "just the keys"? For example, show us the existing data, and what you'd like to store in the "merged" file.